# Incorrect values in array

Tags: c#, sql, report-designer

While I execute code I receive an error for variable template in "if" that says:

> Value cannot be zero/null. Parameter: source

```
int id =Convert.ToInt32(GetCurrentColumnValue("ID"));
var query = string.Format("SELECT ttw_value1663 from mvv.tg_towary_mv where ttw_idtowaru = {0}", id);
var result = DbManager.Execute(query) ;
int[] template= result.GetValue<int[]>(0,0);

if (template.Contains(2181))
{
    Detail.Visible=false;
}
```

I checked query using PgAdmin and I have 2 values inside. Data example: array int[2181,2182]

Comment: Never use `string.Format` to fillin database query values. https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-injectie

Comment: Can you check (with breakpoint for example) the value of `template` just before the if statement please? If it is null for example.

Comment: When I try to get  label5.Text = template[0].ToString(); I receive an Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I think you are getting null data in template variable, just add a breakpoint and check the data.

Comment: I checked code. I do get data from querry as I should.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, SQL is smart. I just converted array in query to text and it works just fine.

Complete code:

```
public void XtraReport_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    // List<int> templates =new List<int>();
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(GetCurrentColumnValue("ID"));
    var query = string.Format("SELECT ttw_value1663::text from mvv.tg_towary_mv where ttw_idtowaru = {0}", id);

    var result = DbManager.Execute(query);

    string template = result.GetValue<string>(0,0);
    label5.Text = template;

    // for (int i = 0; i < template.Length; i++)
    //{
    //     templates.Add(template[i]);
    //}

    if (template.Contains("2181"))
    {
        Detail.Visible = false;
    }
}
```